How can i set a different base for my assets in VueJS Vite
I have a VueJS Vite project which for several reasons has to be built into a /vue/ directory within the root of an existing project.
This is the folder structure:
project
│   Controllers
│   ...    
│
└───Vue <!-- Base App -->
│   │   vite.config.ts
│   │
│   └───src
│       │   App.vue
│       │
│       └───assets
│           │   image-test.webp
│           │   ...
│
└───wwwroot
│   └───css
│   └───img
│   └───vue <!-- Build Directory -->
│       │   index.html
│       │
│       └───assets
│           │   image-test.webp
│           │   ...

This works fine for everything except assets, so considering the following view:
<script setup lang="ts">
    import imageSource from '@/assets/image-test.webp';
</script>
<template>
    <img :src="imageSource" />
</template>

When the page is built the image fails to display, because the base URL is set to / however the 'application' resides in the base /vue/


So if we manually change the URL to /vue/assets/image-test.webp then the image shows as it should:


How can i get the assets to use the base /vue/ but everything else to use the base /?
I've tried the obvious fix of adding into our vite config this line: base: '/vue', and then everything does work as it should from an asset point of view, but our URL's change to always include /vue at the start i.e.
Before: /Controller/Method/Param
After: /vue/Controller/Method/Param

Have you tried the root option? https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#root

Yes, but this seems to generate the same static asset url of /assets/image-test.webp as oppose to where the image resides in: /vue/assets/image-test.webp

@ is just an alias for /src.  why not import from '@/vue/assets/image-test.webp'?  if the need is to not include the /vue/ segment, you could create another alias in vite.config.js, e.g. @assets for path /src/vue/assets

Please, clarify what your project structure looks like. You're supposed to build to ./dist, and assets are resided in ./src/assets, relatively to project root. This is supposed to be unaffected by urls. You can move /dist to any location to match the structure of web root you need, it's unclear how /vue that you mentioned is related

Thanks @yoduh but because the url structure is specific to runtime, i can't reference the assets in this way as the /vue directory doesn't exist.
I've added the folder structure to try and better clarify this as requested by @EstusFlask

Have you tried serving your assets from the /public folder but configuring the folder to be placed in /vue? Looks like there's a documentation where you can configure the public directory with an absolute file system path, in this case, the /vue folder outside the app: https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#publicdir

I can't seem to get this to work either @Airah.
As a workaround this seems to work... but there must be a better way!
const myImage = '/vue' + new URL('@/assets/my-image-name.png', import.meta.url).pathname
